# fetch response 404 but page exists

Tags: javascript, php, json, fetch

I'm have this Fetch code (POST) but the response says `status: 404` even though when I open the url in the browser, the page exists and returns a JSON. when I changed the url to `https://httpbin.org/post` it returns a normal data.. and when I use the same url but with GET method (without any `init` parameters for the fetch method) it returns `status: 200`.

what am I doing wrong?

when I open the url in the browser:
[image: json in browser]

php controller

```
/*
 * filepath: application/modules/test/controllers/test.php
*/
public function homepage()
{
  $this->load->view('home', $this->data);
}

public function get_result()
{
  $response = [
    'status' => 0,
    'message' => 'abcde',
  ];
  echo json_encode($response);
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Button1">

    <script src="/assets/js/test_fetch.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
/*
 * filepath: /assets/js/test_fetch.js
*/
/*!
 * Filename: test_fetch.js
 * Tanggal: 20220214
 * Author: david santana
 * script utk belajar ttg penggunaan fetch API
 * Copyright Gotravelly.com@2022
*/
const myBtn1 = document.querySelector('#btnSubmit');
console.log(myBtn1);
myBtn1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // fetch data from server
    const url = '/test/get_results';
    // const url = 'https://httpbin.org/post';
    let myData = {
        user_id: 123,
        name: 'david',
    };
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(myData)
    })
        .then(response => console.log(response));
});
```

Comment: Are you using some framework? Do you have a router? Does it differentiate between GET and POST requests? In the browser, the URL is `/en/test/get_results` (based on your screen shot) but in your fetch, you're only using `/test/get_result`, which is not the same URL.

Comment: yes, I'm using Codeigniter 3 with some routes settings, but the weird thing is that the same url can be used for GET method, but not POST method.

Answer (score 0):

never mind, my colleague pointed out to me that I didn't add the csrf and I need to use FormData in the `body` parameter.. after I tried it, it works!

but then I tried to use Object with the same csrf key-value pair like this, but it doesn't work

```
let myData = {
  user_id: 123,
  name: 'david',
};
let csrf_name = document.querySelector('#csrf').attributes['name'].value;
let csrf = document.querySelector('#csrf').value;
myData[csrf_name] = csrf;
```

which brings me to a new question (if I may ask a follow-up question): does POST needs to always use a `FormData` as `body` parameter?

Comment: Missing CSRF shouldn't give you a 404 though. That's just odd. 404 means "resource (page) not found". And even if you send data in an unexpected format, it shouldn't give you 404. And no, you don't have to send it as FormData. You can send it however you want and handle it manually in PHP. However, if you use either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (default for HTML forms) or `multipart/form-data`, PHP will populate the `$_POST` variable for you. If you send it in some other format (like json), you need to fetch the body and parse it yourself. It's still a valid request.